# React - Updating State From a Child Component, Then Doing Something Based on State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, components, use-state

New to React hooks and state, trying to figure out why my code isn't working.

I have an `App.js` file and a child component called `Menu.js`. Essentially, `Menu.js` contains a menu that I want to show if a variable called `isOpen` is `true`, and hide if `isOpen` is `false`. I have added the function at the parent level on `App.js`, as I have another component that needs to be able to update the state of `isOpen` as well, but that component is not relevant to my question. Here is the relevant code:

**App.js:**

```
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleState = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  console.log(isOpen); 
    // This will console log either true or false

  const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".hamburgermenu");
  const mobileMenu = document.querySelector(".mobilemenu");
    // These are elements on the child component, Menu.js

  if (isOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add("open");
    mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "5";
      // This should reveal the menu if the value of isOpen is true
  } else {
      menuBtn.classList.remove("open");
      mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "0";
        // This should hide the menu if the value of isOpen is false
  }

return (
  <div>
    <Menu togglestate={toggleState} /> 
      // Passing togglestate down to Menu.js as a prop
  </div>
  );
}
```

**Menu.js:**

```
export default function Menu(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="hamburgermenu" onClick={props.togglestate}>Stuff in here</div>
      // Clicking this div will toggle the value of isOpen between true and false
      <div className="mobilemenu">Stuff in here</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try to run that, my whole application breaks and I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')` at `menuBtn.classList.remove("open");`

I *know* that my problem lies in that the default state is `false`, so it will first try to run the `else` statement. However, because the class `open` hasn't been added to the `menuBtn` element yet, there is no `open` class to remove, and it's erroring out.

I tried to add another nested `if/else` statement within the original `else` statement, basically saying that *if* the element has the class called `open`, remove it, like this:

```
  if (isOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add("open");
    mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "5";
  } else {
      if (menuBtn.classList.contains("open")) {
        menuBtn.classList.remove("open");
        mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "0";
      } else {
          mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "0";
      }
  }
```

I also tried moving away from classes entirely and just changing the styles directly as a test, like this:

```
if (menuOpen) {
  menuBtn.style.display = "block";
  mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "5";
} else {
  menuBtn.style.display = "none";
  mobileMenu.style.zIndex = "0";
}
```

But I *still* got an error at the same line, `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')` at `menuBtn.style.display = "block";`

I know this is all a little messy. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but this is how I would go about it with the knowledge that I do have. If there is an easier way, I am open to suggestions!

Comment: You can try [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for your `menuBtn.style.display`

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the z-index for mobileMenu as well. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General idea in React is to not have to deal with the DOM directly with stuff like `document.querySelector(".hamburgermenu")`

Instead of creating a new function `toggleState`, you can directly pass the setter function `setIsOpen` into the Menu function as follows (along with the current open state)

```
<Menu isOpen={isOpen} togglestate={setIsOpen} />
```

Then your whole if-else condition can be simplified down to a ternary operator as follows:

```
export default function Menu({ isOpen, togglestate }) {
    return (
        <>
            <div
                className={'hamburgermenu' + isOpen ? ' open' : ''}
                onClick={() => togglestate(!isOpen)}
            >
                // Clicking this div will toggle the value of isOpen between true and
                false
            </div>
            <div className="mobilemenu" style={{ zIndex: isOpen ? 5 : 1 }}>
                Stuff in here
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: After some trial and error, I got this method to work with my real code. Thank you so much Aneesh!